# How to calculate this alternating sum?

Tags: analysis

I was wondering how (and if it's even possible) to calculate the following series:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{1}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{1^1} - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} - \frac{1}{4^4} + \cdots
$$
I know it's convergent, of course, but I don't know how to get the value. I've managed an expression for the denominator of the partial sums, but not one for the numerator.

Comment: You should add to the question what you managed to do so far so that others don't have to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a closed form. It's well known that this value is $\int_0^1x^xdx$, which is called [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Answer (score 1):

Well first thing I've thaught of was using the fact that : $$ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\right)\left(\forall x>0\right),\ \frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{x}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(x\right)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{x-1}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y} $$

Thus, for any $ k\in\mathbb{N} $, we have : $$ \frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k!} \int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y}$$

Let's now try to check if we could swith the sum with the integral :

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, we have :

\begin{aligned} \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y}}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!}y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|&=\left|\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}}{k!}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|\\ &\leq\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}}{k!}}\right|\mathrm{d}y} \\ &\leq\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{n+1}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(n+2\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq \frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)^{n+2}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\end{aligned}

Which means : \begin{aligned} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{n}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(n+1\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y}} &= \lim_{n\to +\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}\,\mathrm{d}y}}}\\ &=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!}y^{k}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)y}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-y\left(\mathrm{e}^{-y}+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left(\mathrm{e}^{-y}\right)^{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} \end{aligned}

Thus : $$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}}=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5E%28n-1%29%2Fn%5En) tells us it is about $0.783431$ and will give many more digits if you ask.  It does not offer an exact form.  The alternating series theorem says it takes few terms to get many decimals-$10$ terms gives $10$ decimals and $100$ gives $200$.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can of course use a computer to approximate it. I was wondering how to find an exact form.